# Set default value in textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to set a default value in textbox. It shows "#Name?" instead.

There are three parts of value
1. DocTypeShortName : Document type Name ; PM
2. Y : Year ; 20
3. DocumentNum: Number of Document in that year ; 005

Result I want is PM20005.

```
Dim Y As Long
Dim DocumentNum As String
Dim DocTypeShortName  As String
rsfilter = SQL..
DocumentNum = Format(Right(rsFilter!DocumentNumber, 3) + 1, "000")
Y = Format(Date, "yy")
DocTypeShortName = DLookup("Documentshortname", "tblDocumenttype", "documenttypeID = " & 1)

'  1. Its show only "20001"
Forms!frmplanmonth!DocumentNumber.DefaultValue = Y & DocumentNum

' 2. Not ok, show "#Name?"
Forms!frmplanmonth!DocumentNumber.DefaultValue = DocTypeShortName & Y & DocumentNum

' 3. I try to hard code but its show only "PM"
Forms!frmplanmonth!DocumentNumber.DefaultValue = "'PM'"

' 4. Not ok, show "#Name?"
Forms!frmplanmonth!DocumentNumber.DefaultValue = "'PM'" & Y & DocumentNum
```

It works when I use only year and document number. When I add docTypeShortName it errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a quoted string:

```
Forms!frmplanmonth!DocumentNumber.DefaultValue = "'" & DocTypeShortName & Y & DocumentNum & "'"
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark as answered if you feel so.